When I use VerifyCsrfToken, I lose the data on user auth (laravel 11)
When I define a route in the VerifyCsrfToken file, access to sanctum data disappears, and it returns null.
`
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;
class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
/**
* The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
*
* @var array<int, string>
*/
protected $except = [
    '/check-payment'
];

}`
auth('sanctum')->user()
I have a payment link, and when the user logs in, they go to the gateway. After completing the payment, a POST request is sent to me, and I need the data of the logged-in user.
